# Injecting file in mule using getResourceAsStream

Tags: java, spring, nullpointerexception, initialization, mule

I'm using Mule 3.4. 
I kept a xml file in /src/main/resource/request and using initialize method and resource as stream, tried to load file from classpath and getting Null Pointer Exception

My configuration as follows  spring.xml

```
    <bean id="initSoapFault" class="org.hhmi.transformer.SOAPResponseTransformer" init-method="initialize" />
```

My Flow is following

```
    <spring:beans>
     <spring:import resource="classpath:conf/spring.xml"/>
     </spring:beans>
```

My transformer class is code snippet is following

```
    public void initialize() throws IOException {
     try {
       inputStream =Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("classpath:request/soapFault.xml");
       docXmlResponse = IOUtils.toString(inputStream);
        } finally {
       IOUtils.closeQuietly(inputStream);
        }       }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely that you use the "`classpath:`" prefix when invoking `getResourceAsStream()`. That prefix should only be used in conjunction with a Spring [`ResourceLoader`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/ResourceLoader.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29), but not with a standard Java [`classloader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: I'm trying to inject XML file into mule and using xpath replace the value. 
I used spring resource loader to inject file. 
        
       inputStream =resource.getInputStream(); 

but my problem how to get bean in mule for use it later.

Answer (score 0):

IT's working. I'm putting code snippet, it may help others

to get bean in transformer. I use following

```
      private volatile ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context;

     public SOAPResponseTransformer()  {
      context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(getConfigResources());
     }

 protected String getConfigResources()
{
    return "conf/spring.xml";
}
```

Then call where ever you need bean

```
  ResourceInjection injection =  (ResourceInjection) context.getBean("initSoapFault");

  injection.getter Method
```